# How do I satisfy the Unused Variable rule from PEP8 if I don't need a variable returned by a function?

Tags: python, pep8

When having a function in Python that returns a couple of variables, 
for example:

```
row, column = search_in_table(table_name, search_for)
```

Sometimes you only need to use one of the variables returned by the function. But when this happens, the line is marked with a PEP8 `Unused Variable` warning.

How can I handle this situation so I can comply with all the PEP8 rules?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, depending on your taste, you can do either one of two things:

1. Follow the Python convention for unused variables and replace every one with an underscore:

   ```
   # We only need row
   row, _ = search_in_table(table_name, search_for)
   ```

   or:

   ```
   # We only need column
   _, column = search_in_table(table_name, search_for)
   ```
2. Index the return value of the function:

   ```
   row = search_in_table(table_name, search_for)[0]
   ```

   or:

   ```
   column = search_in_table(table_name, search_for)[1]
   ```

   This last solution works because, technically, Python functions can never return more than one value.  Instead, they can return a *tuple* of values:

   ```
   >>> def func():
   ...     # This is equivalent to:  return (1, 2)
   ...     return 1, 2
   ...
   >>> func()
   (1, 2)
   >>> type(func())
   <class 'tuple'>
   >>> a,b = func()
   >>> a
   1
   >>> b
   2
   >>> a = func()[0]
   >>> a
   1
   >>> b = func()[1]
   >>> b
   2
   >>>
   ```